# How to uninstall the packages in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to uninstall the packages in pycharm community edition 2017.2 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. But I don't find any clues on the uninstallation .

I am wondering if the packages can be removed by easily dropping the related files in python's dist-packages. The package's path is given as follows:

```
usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall a package

On the Project Interpreter page, in the list of packages, select the ones to be deleted.

Click /help/img/idea/2017.2/delete.png.

The selected packages are removed from disk.

please check

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

https://askubuntu.com/questions/598162/how-to-permanently-remove-pycharm-community

Comment: Your image is just text so i don't see what I'm supposed to click. My minus button that's supposed to remove a package is grayed out.

Comment: same for me, grayed out, any idea?